# frame title as buffer file resets to default after some time

Tags: init-file, frames

In my `~/.emacs` I have the following:

```
(setq frame-title-format
  '("" invocation-name ": "
       (:eval (if (buffer-file-name)
                  (abbreviate-file-name (buffer-file-name))
                "%b"))))
```

which sets the frametitle as file currently opened in the buffer. 
So if `~/.emacs` is opened then the title looks as follows:

```
emacs:~/.emacs
```

However after some time the title defaults to usual

```
emacs@hostname
```

How to go about fixing this?

Comment: Your last sentence is cut in the middle!?

Comment: i have fixed it now.

Comment: Does this happen with `emacs -Q` and after evaluation of your first code section? What does "after some time" mean? Please measure and add the measured time in your question. (It may be relevant.) The problem does not manifest with `emacs -Q` version `GNU Emacs 25.3.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.20) of 2017-09-11` for at least 15 minutes. Thereafter I killed that emacs instance.

Comment: -Q option seems to fix this. But -Q also avoids the customization in .emacs.  When I turn back on the all the customization then the problem shows up again.

Comment: Retry with `emacs -q` (this time the small letter `q`) and evaluating the first lisp section from your question. If this also fixes the problem it is time to bisect your initialization file(s). **Otherwise** you need to inspect your site-startup files and your x-resources.