# How to solve non-persistence emacs frame title?

Tags: frames

Some people had the same issue:

- [frame title as buffer file resets to default after some time](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35926/frame-title-as-buffer-file-resets-to-default-after-some-time)
- [How to make frame-title-format persistent?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/41309/how-to-make-frame-title-format-persistent)

I've tried to change `frame-title-format` value to:

- `(setq frame-title-format '(multiple-frames "%b" ("" invocation-name "@" "foobar")))`
- `(setq frame-title-format "%b")`

Both works for several seconds then changed to default `invocation-name "@" system-name` after switching to several other windows.

This happened only when emacs in non-active window state: when it becomes an inactive window, it uses the default value, but when it becomes active window it uses 'user' frame-title value.

I use I3 Window Manager with stacking layout, so I know exactly when the title reverts back to default inconsistently.

I tried using `emacs -q`, yes the problem disappear. But Anyone knows the solution?

The horrible trick that I can use is setting system-name to fake name `(setq system-name "foo")`, but I'm sure this will create problem in future. Other trick is using `(set-frame-name "Foobar")` but it didn't update even I use `(set-frame-name (concat invocation-name " - " (buffer-name)))`

I don't want my username/machinename in the application title.

Comment: I think you would need to file a bug report or just set the frame name explicitly using the frame-parameter.  I've been setting the frame name parameter for more than 5 years and have yet to see any frame name change inadvertently ...

Comment: If you don't see the problem when you use that code after starting Emacs with `emacs -Q` (you mentioned `emacs -q`, which is slightly different), then bisect your init file to find the culprit. You are likely inflicting this problem on yourself (inadvertently).